# i cant send query_set as context argument to the render method

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

im trying fetch data from db and display it into the page, i get the data properly form db but cant display it.
view.py

```
from books.models import Book
from django.shortcuts import render


def query(request):
  query_set = Book.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'books.html',  {'books', query_set})
```

books.html:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Mostafa Saleh</h1>

<p>first Django web application!</p>

<ul>
  {% for book in books %}
  <li> {{ book.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

</body>
</html>```
````

error message(debug_toolbar):

```
TypeError at /
context must be a dict rather than set.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.2.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
context must be a dict rather than set.
```

i used list method to convert the query_set to dict but it wont work and get me another error:
(debug_toolbar)

```
unhashable type: 'list'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.2.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: `return render(request, 'books.html',  {'books', query_set})` has a typo.  Try `return render(request, 'books.html',  {'books':query_set})`, ie, in an object within curly braces, the format should be `{name:value,name:value}`

Comment: @SamSparx thanks man. it got me about 1 hour. didnt notice that.